# Running angular 2 jasmine tests with karma sometimes fails with "Missing error handler on `socket`"

Tags: node.js, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I currently starting to learn angular (v2) and wanted to get into testing.

After some unsuccessful tries in my first project, I cloned the official quickstart repo from here:

https://github.com/angular/quickstart

and tried to launch the tests there with:
`npm test`

Sometimes the tests work as expected, but sometimes I get a strange error:

```
[1] Missing error handler on `socket`.
[1] TypeError: Cannot set property '60946738' of null
```

I've found several hints with a similar error (the socket part) but with `(msg || "").replace is not a function` on the next line. This error seems to be different.

From the console output I see that the tests are actually run. Looks like the error occurs right after the tests (the one test failing is actually expected, as I intentionally changed the smoke test to make the test fail). Apart from this test I changed nothing to the project.

I'm under the impression, that the error occurs more frequently with failing tests (but this could be totally unrelated).

Any idea what's wrong?

A larger part of the console output:

```
[1] 26 09 2016 15:47:03.221:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/systemjs.config.extras.js
[1] Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0) LOG: 'WARNING: System.import could not load "systemjs.config.extras.js"; continuing without it.'
[1]
[1] Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0) LOG: Error{originalErr: Error{}}
[1]
    Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Smoke test should run a passing test FAILED
[1]     Expected true to equal false, 'should pass'.
    Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.109 secs / 0.1 secs)
[1] 26 09 2016 15:47:03.732:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/systemjs.config.extras.js
[1] Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0) LOG: 'WARNING: System.import could not load "systemjs.config.extras.js"; continuing without it.'
[1]
[1] Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0) LOG: Error{originalErr: Error{}}
[1]
    Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1] Missing error handler on `socket`.
[1] TypeError: Cannot set property '60946738' of null
[1]     at createHtmlResults (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\cc-dashboard-qs\cc-dashboard-qs\node_modules\karma-htmlfile-reporter\index.js:57:32)
[1]     at initializeHtmlForBrowser (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\cc-dashboard-qs\cc-dashboard-qs\node_modules\karma-htmlfile-reporter\index.js:78:5)
[1]     at HTMLReporter.onBrowserStart (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\cc-dashboard-qs\cc-dashboard-qs\node_modules\karma-htmlfile-reporter\index.js:91:5)
[1]     at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\cc-dashboard-qs\cc-dashboard-qs\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
[1]     at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
[1]     at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
[1]     at Browser.onStart (C:\Users\username\Documents\Projekte\cc-dashboard-qs\cc-dashboard-qs\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:126:13)
```